# MongoEngien: method .all() raises an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__auto_convert'

Tags: python, mongodb

I have problem with getting objects from mongodb using MongoEngine:
when I call BaseForm.objects.all() it raises an exception:

```
...    
obj = cls(__auto_convert=False, _created=created, __only_fields=only_fields, **data)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__auto_convert'
```

In mongodb console records are displayed properly.

My model:

```
class BaseController(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    type = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}


class RadioButton(BaseController):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(BaseController, self).__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.type = 'radiobutton'


class CheckBox(BaseController):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(BaseController, self).__init__()
        self.title = title
        self.type = 'checkbox'


class BaseFormController(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    controllers = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('BaseController'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}


class BaseForm(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    controllers = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('BaseFormController'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue in any ways? I think I get a similar issue...